# Flexbox wraps outside of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I've created a header including a navigation with flexbox. My problem is, as soon as the screen gets resized to approx. 1200px the line wraps and my navigation buttons spill outside of thecontainer - how can I fix this?

http://codepen.io/TimRos/pen/xGVwQE

```
.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 150px;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: That depends on how you would like the navigation to behave instead. Should it stay the same and break through the left of the containing element? Or should it wrap into two or more lines which should all be visible?

Comment: ideally it would wrap into more lines but stay confined in its container so its still usable until the media query kicks in and converts the whole header into a column. the space on the left is a logo with a background image by the way so that should still stay clear of any other elements

Comment: well, then the question arises, what happens to the content below?
Anyway, this seems to work in firefox, although a quick check tells me it might look different in IE: [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbdXJj](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbdXJj)

Comment: thanks that was definitely helpful - I realized that the problem is the fixed height of the .main-nav flexbox container. setting the container to a max-height: 200px; instead of height: 150px will allow the navigational items to break  staying confined in the container (creating an ugly line of free space below the logo in the process...maybe that could be fixed by stretching the logo?)

Comment: is it absolutely necessary for the logo to be a child <li> of the navigation? As it is not really part of the flow, you might consider just placing it outside of your nav and handling the nav separately. That way you could position the logo absolutely at the bottom of the container, no matter where that may be

Comment: that is actually a good idea, will try it as soon as I get home, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the fixed height `(height: 150px;)`. This will let the nav resize when the menu items wrap like this:

```
.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: I was surprised that even having `height: 100%;` would cause this error. Thanks!